# WebMethod não é chamado (disparado) através do PageMethod

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, webmethods, pagemethods

Não estou conseguindo efetuar o disparo de um `WebMethod` em um projeto criado no Visual Studio 2013 (WebForms Application).

Se eu criar um projeto, por exemplo, no Visual Studio 2008 e migrar para o Visual Studio 2013, funciona corretamente. Se eu criar um projeto novo no Visual Studio 2013 ocorre o problema referido.

Pesquisei muito para ver se é necessário adicionar alguma chave no `web.config`, mas não encontrei nada a respeito.

**Segue o código do ASPX:**

```asp
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestePageMethods._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function testeClick() {            
            PageMethods.SayHello("Name");        
        }  

    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Say Hello" onclick="testeClick();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**E o aspx.vb:**

```vb
Partial Public Class _Default
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

 End Sub

 <System.Web.Services.WebMethod(True)> _
 Public Shared Function SayHello(ByVal name As String) As String
    Return "Hello " & name
 End Function

End Class
```

EDIT:
Pessoal, mais uma informação que descobri agora:

Trabalhando somente no VS2013:

- novo projeto.
- Web - ASP.NET Web Application.
- Selecionar o template "Empty".
- Inserir uma página "Default.aspx", o WebMethod funciona normalmente...

Agora, se criar um novo projeto e selecionar o template "WebForms", não funciona...

Será que não existe nenhuma referência cruzando? ou alguma configuração diferente?

Comment: Você chegou a verificar se existe algum erro no console de erros do browser (JavaScript). Pode ajudar a identificar o problema.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno talles. Não ocorre nenhum erro de JS... nem warning. Simplesmente não acontece nada. Seria como se estivesse false a tag "EnablePageMethods"... mas ela está "true". Só consigo fazer funcionar quando crio um projeto com o template "Empty" no VS2013, se selecionar o template "WebForms", não funciona... e meu projeto inteiro está no WebForms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Achei a solução para meu problema: O que impedia que o `WebMethod` fosse chamado era a referência com o `System.Web.Optimization`. Não sei bem como ele faz isso, mas como não usarei ele no momento, decidi remover:

`System.Web.Optimization` e `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms`

Também é necessário remover do `web.config` o seguinte:

```
<namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
</namespaces>

<add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" 

namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" 

publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Tudo ok agora! Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram com o problema! :)

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, o problema não era por causa do System.Web.Optimization.

Na verdade, o problema se dá por causa do porque 
Para fazer essa chamada do PageMethod funcionar na sua aplicação WebForms você precisa alterar o arquivo RouteConfig.cs" (localizado em "~/App_Code/RoutConfig.cs"), da seguinte forma:

settings.AutoRedirectMode
 = RedirectMode.Permanent;

Para:

settings.AutoRedirectMode
 = RedirectMode.Off;

O mesmo vale para chamadas com Jquery.